# How to generate a cartesian product with a dependent cartesian product

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

How do I get the following desired results using itertools or similar? `itertools.product` with Boolean x Boolean x Range x Range produces many undesired results.

`A1, A2` should be iterated only in case `use_A is True`

`B1, B2` should be iterated only in case `use_B is True`

It has to be the most efficient way, because full `product_config` has more than 5 bln different combinations.

```
product_config = {
    'use_A': [False, True],
    'A1': range(3),
    'A2': range(3),
    'use_B': [False, True],
    'B1': range(3),
    'B2': range(3)
}

# Desired results:
res = [
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': False},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 0, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 2},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 1, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 2},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 0, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 1, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': True, 'A1': 2, 'A2': 2, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 2},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 2},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 2},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 0},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 1},
    {'use_A': False, 'use_B': True, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 2},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools` we can use the following:

```
import itertools
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
b1 = [False, True]
t1 = itertools.product(b1, b1)
res = []
for t in t1:
    i1 = itertools.product(range(3), range(3))
    for i in i1:
        rdict = {'use_A': t[0], 'use_B': t[1]}
        if not t[0] and not t[1]:
            res.append(rdict)
            break
        if t[0]:
            rdict['A1'] = i[0]
            rdict['A2'] = i[1]
        if t[1]:
            rdict['B1'] = i[0]
            rdict['B2'] = i[1]
        res.append(rdict)
pp.pprint(res)
```

Output

```
[   {'use_A': False, 'use_B': False},
    {'B1': 0, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 0, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 0, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 1, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 1, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 1, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 2, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 2, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'B1': 2, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': False, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': False},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 0, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 1, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 0, 'A2': 2, 'B1': 0, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 0, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 1, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 1, 'A2': 2, 'B1': 1, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 0, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 0, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 1, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 1, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True},
    {'A1': 2, 'A2': 2, 'B1': 2, 'B2': 2, 'use_A': True, 'use_B': True}]
```